# Responsive Design - how to get my image on left to take up whole screen

Tags: css, responsive-design

Im using media queries, and trying to learn more about responsive design.

**media query css**

```
@media screen 
  and (max-width: 480px){ 
    #header .left {
        float:none;
        width:100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
        #header .left img{
            margin:0%;
            width:100%;
            height:auto;
        }

    #header .right {
        float:none;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        clear:both;
    }

  }
```

**My regular css looks like:**

```
    #header .left{
        width:17.95833335%;
        float:left;
    }
        #header .left img{
            margin:0%;
            max-width:100%;
            max-height:100%;
            -moz-border-radius:5px 20px 5px; -webkit-border-radius:5px 20px 5px; border-radius:5px 20px 5px;
        }

#header .right{
        width:79.95833335%;
        max-height:100%;
        min-height:100%;
        margin:0% 1%;
        /*background-color: red;*/
        background:
            linear-gradient(27deg, #151515 5px, transparent 5px) 0 5px,
            linear-gradient(207deg, #151515 5px, transparent 5px) 10px 0px,
            linear-gradient(27deg, #222 5px, transparent 5px) 0px 10px,
            linear-gradient(207deg, #222 5px, transparent 5px) 10px 5px,
            linear-gradient(90deg, #1b1b1b 10px, transparent 10px),
            linear-gradient(#1d1d1d 25%, #1a1a1a 25%, #1a1a1a 50%, transparent 50%, transparent 75%, #242424 75%, #242424);
            background-color: #131313;
            background-size: 20px 20px;
        -moz-border-radius:5px;
        -webkit-border-radius:5px;
        border-radius:5px;
        -webkit-flex: 1;
        -ms-flex: 1;
        flex: 1;
        float:right;
    }
```

**html**

```
<div class="left">
                    <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='my_pic.jpg') }}" alt="My Pic" />
                </div><!--left-->
                <div class="right">
                    <h2>
                        Test test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test</h2>
</div><!--right-->
```

I'm currently seeing:
[image: img]

I want the black area on the right(`.right`) to move down, and the image on the left (`.left`) to take up the whole screen.

How can i accomplish this?

Thanks

Comment: Paste HTML code and create a jsfiddle reproducing the bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your `#header .left img` rule contains `max-width: 100%`, but for what you want it has to be `width: 100%`(and `height: auto`)

Comment: Thanks for that, added that, but it didnt make the image the whole screen...updating css to show. Also updated image too

Comment: Do both left and right need width: 100%;height: auto; ?

Comment: in your css, is the order of the rules as you listed them here or (as it *should* be) the other way round (media Queries AFTER regular styles)?

Comment: media queries are a seperate css file. first regular css is loaded, then the media query file, with the media declarations

Comment: take out the `height: 100%` from both left and right rules- it doesn't really make sense and might cause problems. Also, I'd try it without the flex parameter (put `flex: none`in the media query for `.right`). What CSS does `#header` have?

Answer (score 0):

You could give at the image `width:100%` and `clear:both` to make the black text box to go under the image.
If you could provide the html it could be helpful.

--edit--

As I said with a `width:100%` and `clear:both`given at the left class will make the work for you.

Comment: Unfortunately adding this, increased the image on the left a bit, but not completely... updating css above to show you. Any further thoughts??

Comment: I have played around a little bit with jsfiddle and your code and it worked well, the image was always on top and the text was under it, could you give us the url so we can see the css rule that are applied in real time?